# SP2013 CSOM C# Update List

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, csom

```
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(Site);
ctx.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, passWord, "dmz");               
List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(SpList);
ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
ctx.Load(items); // loading all the fields              
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (var item in items)
{
    if (((FieldUrlValue)(item["VideoSetExternalLink"])).Url.ToString() != VideoURL)
    {
        ((FieldUrlValue)(item["VideoSetExternalLink"])).Url = vp.VideoURL;
        item.Update(); 
    }
}
ctx.Load(items);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Works Fine NO ERROR. But the list is not getting updated. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(Site);
ctx.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, passWord, "dmz");               
List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(SpList);
ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
ctx.Load(items); // loading all the fields              
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (var item in items)
{
    if (((FieldUrlValue)(item["VideoSetExternalLink"])).Url.ToString() != VideoURL)
    {
        FieldUrlValue va = ((FieldUrlValue)(item["VideoSetExternalLink"]));
        va.Url = vp.VideoURL;
        item["VideoSetExternalLink"] = va;
        item.Update(); 
    }
}
ctx.Load(items);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

This is how i Fixed the issue.
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last ctx.Load(items), because you are not sending the update to sharepoint instead you are reloading the items values

```
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(Site);
ctx.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, passWord, "dmz");               
List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(SpList);
ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
ctx.Load(items); // loading all the fields              
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (var item in items)
{
    if (((FieldUrlValue)(item["VideoSetExternalLink"])).Url.ToString() != VideoURL)
    {
        ((FieldUrlValue)(item["VideoSetExternalLink"])).Url = vp.VideoURL;
        item.Update(); 
    }
}
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: I fixed the issue by creating a FieldUrlValue object and assigning the value then modifying the object then pass it back to item.

eg:

FieldUrlValue va = ((FieldUrlValue)(item["VideoSetExternalLink"]));
va.Url = vp.VideoURL;
item["VideoSetExternalLink"] = va;

Thanks for your Help though.